# Converting list of lists to numpy array giving unexpected results

Tags: python, pandas-groupby, numpy-ndarray

I have a list of lists that I'm trying to convert to a numpy array using `numpy.array`. I can't share the actual code because it's proprietary; I've tried to come up with a simple analogue example but I don't get the same problem.

The simple analogue is that I have `N` pandas DataFrames like these:

```
import pandas as pd


df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,1.5],[1,3.2],[2,1.2],[2,3.1]], columns=['month', 'target'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,1.5],[1,3.2],[2,1.2],[2,3.1]], columns=['month', 'target'])
```

I then group by month, sum target, and store the normalised array in a dict.

```
import numpy as np


arrays = {}
arrays[1] = np.array(df.groupby('month').sum().target / df.groupby('month').sum().target.max())
arrays[2] = np.array(df2.groupby('month').sum().target / df2.groupby('month').sum().target.max())
```

I finally convert the arrays into a single array using a list comprehension.

```
np.array([arrays[x] for x in arrays.keys()])
```

In this example, I get what I want, which is

```
array([[1.        , 0.91489362],
       [1.        , 0.91489362]])
```

however, when I use my actual data, I get this

```
array([list([1.        , 0.91489362]),
       list([1.        , 0.91489362])])
```

If I convert them to arrays in the list comprehension, I get this

```
array([array([1.        , 0.91489362]),
       array([1.        , 0.91489362])])
```

I've done all the type changes and variable transformations I can think of, indeed, I've converted everything into the format I use for the above analogue and checked the types of all the variables I'm using, but no change.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: With your actual data, are all the lists in the result the same length?

Comment: You're right! I have 133 DFs and one was a value short!

Comment: Fascinating! I was wondering, how python decides wheter it writes `array([0, 1, 2])` or just `[0,1,2]`.